# Why are frontend frameworks in NPM?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

When I’m looking at some github projects and tutorials I look at the package.json file and see frontend frameworks listed as the dependencies quite a lot. I don’t get it. I thought Node was backend? My understanding is that to install frontend frameworks you dl them directly from their website or github or use a CDN then link them in your pages - all this has nothing to do with Node.

Even if I did install a framework through Node doesn’t it save it to the node_modules folder? There must be a reason for it as I’ve seen a lot of projects list them in their package.json file. Can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: @quentin have a look at the dupe, it's terrible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NodeJS is not only a "server" in the sense that it is a programmable webserver, it is a JavaScript runtime. You can use it to serve webpages, but you can also use the NodeJS server as a parser / generator for JavaScript (meaning: reading and writing files on the system). If you use one of the frontend frameworks like react and angular, you install the packages just to get their sourcecode and not to actually run the code on the server. Then you use a bundler like webpack to turn the code you've written and the code from the modules into one (or multiple) large chunks of minified frontend code. You can usually find those generated files inside the `/dist` or `/build` folder. Now to get these files to clients, you can use NodeJS as a server too, serving the files to the clients. That way, the packages "installed" on your server end up on your client.

Comment: "that it is a programmable webserver" — It isn't, you can just program a webserver on top of it.

Comment: @quentin I tried to make clear that "server" does not mean that it has to answer http requests. I'ts late so my english might not be that well anymore ... I'd be grateful if you have a better way to phrase that.

Comment: thanks for explaining this Jonas. @Quetin, I would say this similar not but not the same as the dupe.

Comment: @JonasWilms I saw soemthing similar to that here https://github.com/witcher3map/witcher3map. It has "leaflet" as a dependency then a grunt task called  build" would build a bundle based on this and some other js. Another question around this though, in the witcher example, the original unbundled js is an a folder called assets but the html doesn't look there for the scripts; after it's been bundled, how would you then go back and do DEV work on the JS? I'd imagine it'd be pretty hard giving that the code would now be hard to read.

Comment: There are so called sourcemaps. That's a completely different wuestion though.

Comment: Could you give me any pointers on where I can read up/learn about these types of methods? I've done a lot of tutorials and read guides about node and JS but I've never seen anything on like how to use this method of building a website and bundling code together for the frontend, or how to use source maps to reverse engineer code. Now I know what they’re called I can go and google them, but I'm struggling to find a good source which teaches these "good practices" so to speak.